# задачка на повторный вызов функции

Tags: функции

Реализовать once – функцию, которая принимает другую функцию, в качестве аргумента, и возвращает новую версию этой функции. 
Новая версия должна возвращать то же, что и оригинальная функция, но все последующие вызовы должны возвращать результат самого первого вызова. 
Пример:

```
    let inc = a => a + 1;
    let incOnce = once(inc);
     let res1 = incOnce(42); //res1 is 43
    let res2 = incOnce(77); //res2 is 43, NOT 78
```

Требования:
1. Не допустимы повторные вызовы функции-аргумента 2. Функция once должна корректно работать с функциями нескольких аргументов 3. Функция once должна корректно работать с методами 4. Функция once должна корректно работать с функциями, которые кидают исключения. В таких случаях, новая функция должна выбрасывать одно и то же исключение при всех последующих вызовах.

Написал пробный код, но счетчик не работает:

```js
    let counter = 0;
    let firstCall;
    let once = ()=>{
    
        if (counter>1){
            return firstCall
        }
            counter ++
        firstCall = inc;
            return inc
    
    };
    let inc =a=>a+1;
    
    let incOnce = once(inc);
    
    let res1 = incOnce(42);
    let res2 = incOnce(77);
    console.log(res1, res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

1, 2 и 4:

```js
let once = (func) => {

  let counter = 0;
  let result;
  let ex;
  
  return function() {
    if (counter++ == 0) {
      try {
        result = func.apply(null, arguments)
      } catch(e) {
        ex = e;
        throw e;
      }
    }
    if (ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
    return result;
  };
};

let inc = a => a + 1;

let incOnce = once(inc);

let res1 = incOnce(42);
let res2 = incOnce(77);
console.log(res1, res2);
```

Вот это не понял:

> 3. Функция once должна корректно работать с методами